# How to use flask-login with React JS

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, flask-login

I have created a ReactJS based application using `create-react-app` and am starting it using webpack on port `3000`.

I have also created a Flask based backend (hosted on port `5000`) through which I am exposing a few APIs and am consuming using `fetch` api in my application.

Now I want to setup a login functionality using `flask-login`. I followed the [tutorial from realpython](https://realpython.com/using-flask-login-for-user-management-with-flask/) and could expose a `/login` endpoint in my flask app where I send a `POST` request with user's `email` and `password` credentials and manage to execute `login_user`, so this seems to be fine. However, if I try to access any other API, flask still doesn't think that I am logged in.

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({email, password})
}.then(...)
```

I inspected the response to login request in chrome dev tools' network tab and it seems that flask is sending some cookies, but my browser doesn't seem to be sending any cookies in subsequent requests.

Comment: I think it's easier if you don't do cross origin and set up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) for your dev environment.

Comment: my prod environ has a proxy setup. i didn't want to spend effort doing the same in dev environ so slacked off.

Comment: Should work if setup properly. I just started learning Flask and am working with a React frontend. By using the `@login_required` decorator I am able to protect my routes and by importing `current_user` from `flask` I can see the current user that is logged in, in any of my other `api` endpoints. Also, I believe you are trying to send `json` over the network so you want to set your `headers` with the correct `Content-Type`. Not sure if any of this applies to you as your setup might be trying to render a template or working with perhaps some `FlaskForms` perhaps you can post your backend code

Comment: It is all while using `flask-login`